# Restict Internet Connection Except using Proxy

Tags: windows, active-directory, proxy, group-policy, internet

Given (as-is)

1. A router with DHCP enabled
2. An Active Directory Server
3. Two Windows 7 clients joined the domain

Planning (to-be)

1. A proxy server
2. Two clients are set to restrict internet connection except using the proxy server

Question

1. How to achieve the restriction? by network setting level, or by Group Policy level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do this at the router, not the PCs. Don't allow the PCs in question to go outside the network; only allow the proxy to go outside the network. Use ACLs or NAT or whatever works for your router.

You do need to configure the PCs to use the proxy of course, and either a GPO or WPAD is a good method of doing that.